# visual mode/highlighting/selecting text on uzbl?

Tags: arch-linux, vim, browser, highlighting

Is there a way to do a vim-like visual mode to select text with uzbl? Or any way to select text in uzbl with the keyboard? I installed arch-linux recently, and I haven't gotten my touchpad working. But I'm starting to think that I'd like to live without it for most purposes, and figuring out how to highlight text within the browser with only the keyboard would be nice (and, preferably in a way similar to vim).

I've searched around quite a bit for a way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It has been years since I used Uzbl, but in Vimprobable (another webkit keyboard-driven browser) there is a cursor mode, so you just `/` to search for your string, then enter cursor mode and highlight what you need: perhaps Uzbl does the same?

Comment: The relevant variable in Uzbl is [caret_browsing](http://www.uzbl.org/readme.php)...

Comment: @jasonwryan I tried that, doesn't quite work the same. caret_browsing does sound like what I'm looking for, but I couldn't figure out how to do anything with it. I tried editing my uzbl config to let me access caret_browsing mode, but was unsuccessful. I'm just using dwb now, works fine.

Comment: FWIW dwb is no longer supported...

Comment: Darn, wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the notice. I assumed it was since it was still available in the default pacman repos. Perhaps I'll try Vimprobable.

Comment: See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190716 for a fork, or yes, Vimprobable is a solid option.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the link. I'll have to explore my options here. Also, if you compile all of this into an answer, I'll pick it since it doesn't look like other answers are coming up.